# .Net Core 2.0 Console Application not sending messages to Loggly via NLog

Tags: c#, .net-core, nlog, loggly

I have a .NET Core 2.0 (Topshelf) console application that needs to send logs to Loggly.  We have already implemented the same type of application using the NLog, NLog.Targets.Loggly, Topshelf.NLog, loggly-csharp-config, and loggly-csharp.

I added two additional targets, Console and text.  Both of the other targets are working fine.

The customer Loggly key works fine in our .NET 4.71 apps of similar structure with the same packages.

Here is the package reference I have:

```
<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Autofac" Version="4.8.1" />
<PackageReference Include="loggly-csharp" Version="4.6.1.64" />
<PackageReference Include="loggly-csharp-config" Version="4.6.1.64" />
<PackageReference Include="NLog.Targets.Loggly" Version="4.7.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Topshelf" Version="4.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Topshelf.NLog" Version="4.1.0" />
```

Edit: Adding some more implementation code
From App.config:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog" />
    <section name="loggly" type="Loggly.Config.LogglyAppConfig, Loggly.Config, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  </configSections>
...

<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
        autoReload="true"
        throwExceptions="false"
        internalLogLevel="Trace" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">
    <extensions>
      <add assembly="NLog.Targets.Loggly" />
    </extensions>
    <variable name="DefaultLayout" value="${longdate} | ${level:uppercase=true:padding=5} | ${message} | ${exception:format=@} | ${callsite} | ${callsite-linenumber} | ${all-event-properties}" />
    <targets async="true">
      <target xsi:type="File" name="logfile" fileName="logs/log.txt"  layout="${DefaultLayout}"/>
      <target xsi:type="Console" name="console"  layout="${DefaultLayout}"/>
      <target xsi:type="Loggly" name="Loggly" layout="${DefaultLayout}"/>
    </targets>
    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logfile,Loggly,console" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
  <loggly
    xmlns="Loggly"
    applicationName="masked"
    customerToken="masked"
    throwExceptions="true">
    <transport logTransport="Https"/>
    <tags>
      <simple>
        <tag value="DEV"/>
      </simple>
      <complex>
        <tag type="Loggly.HostnameTag" formatter="{0}"/>
        <tag type="Loggly.ApplicationNameTag" formatter="{0}"/>
      </complex>
    </tags>
  </loggly>
```

Internal log appears to be showing that there is at least attempts to hit Loggly.

> 2018-12-12 09:05:09.8816 Debug Targets for
>   Topshelf.Hosts.ConsoleRunHost by level: 2018-12-12 09:05:09.8816 Debug
>   Trace => 2018-12-12 09:05:09.8816 Debug Debug => 2018-12-12
>   09:05:09.8816 Debug Info => 2018-12-12 09:05:09.8816 Debug Warn =>
>   2018-12-12 09:05:09.8816 Debug Error => 2018-12-12 09:05:09.8816 Debug
>   Fatal => 2018-12-12 09:05:10.1486 Trace AsyncWrapper(Name=Loggly):
>   Writing 1 events (Timer) 2018-12-12 09:05:10.1486 Trace
>   AsyncWrapper(Name=console): Writing 1 events (Timer) 2018-12-12
>   09:05:10.1486 Trace AsyncWrapper(Name=logfile): Writing 1 events
>   (Timer) 2018-12-12 09:05:10.1747 Trace Opening

Comment: Please show us some code of how you implemented this.

Comment: Tried enabling NLog Internal Logger ? https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging

Comment: @rolf, Yea, no output from the internal log.

Comment: Try configure `taskPendingLimit="1"` for the NLog-target, and call `NLog.LogManager.Shutdown()` before main-exit.

Comment: Btw. how does NetCore and AppConfig work together? Checked that NetCore loggly-client is able read setup from app.config?

Comment: @RolfKristensen, no changes after the taskPendingLimit check.  The System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager package works with getting connection strings, appsettings, etc, and the other targets for nlog are working fine this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by @RolfKristensen, I tried to manually configure the csharp client via code and it's working fine.  I'll have to move around the configs to the appSettings and have configuration manager pick those up.  I guess loggly-csharp needs better documentation around NOT using their config samples in .NET Core.